# How to add a character special in this php code?

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to add the special character ® in this code:

```
certificate_print_text($pdf, $x, $y + 105, 'C', 'Helvetica', '', 24, $course->fullname);
```

i want to represent something like this: Dentokind® (dentokind is the name of the course)

I hope you can help me.

thank you :)

Comment: tell us what represend every paramaters from your functions. And try to use after course name &copy; html symbol.

Comment: Well &#174; is the HTML code for registered symbol.  Use that?

Comment: echo 'Dentokind'. '&#174;';  try this

Comment: course, is the course on which we are currently in moodle. This line of code represents the course you have passed and writes it to your certificate, ie, this parameter changes (may have another name). What I want is to add ® after the course name. i can't change it in the entire platform, they want it only in the certificate.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the comments, the HTML-Code for the registered trademark symbol is `&#174;` so your line of code should look similar to this:

```
certificate_print_text($pdf, $x, $y + 105, 'C', 'Helvetica', '', 24, $course->fullname."&#174;");
```